# How to add a named element to a R list using a variable counter?

Tags: r

I have number of results to pass back to a calling procedure
I'd like to pass back a named list where each result is numbered.

```
# the following works
# result is a valid result
results = list( "1" = result)
```

When I do the following I end up with results$resultCounter instead of results$'1'

```
resultCounter = 1
results = list( resultCounter = result)
```

How do you pass in the contents of a variable to be the name of an element within a list?

Comment: So if I have an array of values will that names each result in order? i.e. setNames(results, resultCounts)

Comment: Yes, assuming that the number of list elements and the vector of names are of the same length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use `setNames`

```
results <- setNames(result, resultCounter)
```

#### data

```
result <- list(1:5, 6:10)
resultCounter <- 1:2
```